# How to make a Mongo query using "$box" on PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Im trying to make this query on Mongo:

```
{"localization": {"$within" : {"$box" : [ [-3.725502, 40.447323],[-3.659039095404374 , 40.4189327481702]]}}}
```

I translated to an array and it looks like this:

```
array("localization" => array('$within' => array('$box' => array('[[-3.725502, 40.447323]', '[-3.659039095404374 , 40.4189327481702]]'))))
```

And I get no results, if I make the previous Mongo query on the server I get 200 results, but not in PHP. As a result is:

```
object(MongoCursor)#5 (0) { }
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing $box an array of strings in PHP, not an array of arrays.

Try:

`'$box' => array(array(-3.725502, 40.447323), array(-3.659039095404374 , 40.4189327481702'))`